# android code to select audio mp3 and play it

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an application,in which user will select a single audio file and play the audio. 
Then I will pass the audio to the next activity.

Here is my code it select the audio but it gives error `setDataSource Failed:Status=0X80000000` kindly guide me what should I do

```
switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnmusic:
        /*Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File("file:///sdcard/Music");
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");*/
        Intent pickMedia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pickMedia.setType("audio/*");
        startActivityForResult(pickMedia,1);
    break;

protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode,int ResultCode,Intent data)
{
    if(RequestCode==1)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            Uri muri=data.getData();
            String uri=muri.getPath();
            File track=new File(uri);
            if(uri != null)
            {
                Uri urinew = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(track.getAbsolutePath());

            //Toast.makeText(this, uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             MediaPlayer md=new MediaPlayer();
             try{

                 md.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();
                        }

                    });
             md.setDataSource(AudioSelect.this, urinew);
             md.prepare();
             md.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        else
        {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Data Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `getAbsolutePath()` is actually giving you the path?

Comment: Will i solved it.now i simply pass the muri in setdatasource which plays my audio like this  md.setDataSource(AudioSelect.this, muri);
     md.prepare();
     md.start();

Comment: but i want to send this muri to next activity so i can play the song in next activity.please guide me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

**1:** Use Intent to choose audio file from sd card:

```
   Intent audioIntent = new Intent();
   audioIntent.setType("audio/*");
   audioIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(audioIntent,PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
```

**2:** Handle the result in `OnActivityResult`

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null || data.getData() == null) {
            // error
            return;
        }
if (requestCode == PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST) {
            try {
                Uri uri= data.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
                // play audio file using MediaPlayer
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();              
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: `getRealPathFromURI` is a utility method :

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what if I need to open mp3 only, as this will allow picking other formats too.

Comment: @MrNarendra have you tried `audioIntent.setType("audio/mpeg3");`

Answer (score 0):

```
md = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(track.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to send this muri to next activity so i can play the song in next activity.please guide me how can i do this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode,int ResultCode,Intent data)
{
    if(RequestCode==1)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            Uri muri=data.getData();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("uriToPlay",muri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Data Recieved", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Rest of the code (like Media player) in the next Activity.